# How to open a root terminal

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, wine

I am a person that is new to xubuntu using crouton on a chrome book I was wondering how to get the Root terminal open. The reason I want to do this is so I can modify some files that ware left behind by installing wine and removing it 
( Yes I used -Remove -Autoremove and -Purge) I can not do this and also I am morbidly curious so I would like access to the root terminal

Comment: Looks like a decent answer here: http://askubuntu.com/q/515198/57576

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your admin account open a terminal with <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and type ...

```
sudo -i
```

the will ask for the admin password, and then show a `#`. Mind that is terribly easy to royally mess up your system when using `#`.

Mind though this is not required for what you need to do. When you want to remove something you do not own put `sudo` in front of the command and it will remove it.

If there is anything remaining from deleting wine it should be in `/home/$USER/.wine` and all the should be needed is to remove that directory.

Comment: Thank you this worked but I found a option to open programs with "hh" it was from a execution file called ebb and I could remove it because of this thanks!

Comment: cool; glad you got it sorted :)