# How to launch a console application from a shortcut in root?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, root, shortcuts

I have a console application, which I run as root from the shell.
But now, I need to create a shortcut on the Desktop, where I click on it, and it should appear the shell (in root) and the application running.
How can I do this?

I've seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515198/how-to-run-terminal-as-root).

Where I've done the following:

```
sudo apt install gnome-panel

sudo apt install gksu

gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new
```

Where I've set up the shortcut. But if I run the application, nothing works and I do not see the shell.

I'm using `Ubuntu 16.04`.

Comment: Is is going to depend on what version of Ubuntu you are running.

Comment: I'm using 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So inside your .desktop entry you need to put the following on the exec line:

`Exec=gnome-terminal.real -- YOUR_COMMAND`
and on the Terminal line
`Terminal=true`

The `--` in the Exec line means that the command after it will be executed in the new terminal.

So for example if you want to start a python application as root when you click on the desktop icon your `.desktop` file should look something like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=The app name
Icon=/absolute/path/to/an/icon.png
Exec=gnome-terminal.real -- sudo python /absolute/path/to/your/script.py
Comment=Some longer description of what your program does.
Categories=Utility;
Terminal=true
```

So when a user clicks on your desktop icon they will see a terminal window that displays a password prompt like this:

[image: Password prompt after clicking on desktop icon]

And after the prompt your program is run.

Comment: If you want to be able to run it without being prompted for the sudo password you can run `sudo visudo` and a a line like `<USERNAME> <HOSTNAME> = (root) NOPASSWD: <PATH/TO/COMMAND>` as in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/159009/423684)